Use GDAL to extract a part of an raster image
I have an png image where I know the bounds and its CRS.  I have a bbox in a different CRS which I want to use to cut a part from the original image.
How can I do that?
Ultimately I need to do that in a node environment. For that I think I am going to use gdal-async - or is there a better way?
I got a tiny bit further trying it manually:

I download this image:
https://gdi.berlin.de/services/wms/truedop_2023?SERVICE=WMS&request=GetMap&version=1.3.0&layers=truedop_2023&styles=truedop_2023&crs=EPSG%3A25833&width=512&height=512&format=image%2Fpng&bbox=392680.95083132095%2C5816991.938620153%2C393134.43388141005%2C5817424.944091731&transparent=TRUE
it has these outlines:

{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {},
"geometry": {
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
[
[
13.425815172448008,
52.49249712044625
],
[
13.42581523957934,
52.49647748166542
],
[
13.419277533858136,
52.49647748166542
],
[
13.419277600989467,
52.49249712044625
],
[
13.425815172448008,
52.49249712044625
]
]
]
},
"id": 0
}

as far as I understand I have to add the georeference to the image like this:
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_ullr 13.419277600989467 52.49249712044625 13.42581523957934 52.49647748166542  -a_srs EPSG:4326 "truedop_2023-truedop_2023.png" "georef_truedop_2023.tiff"

now I would like to cut a piece out of this image like so:
gdal_translate -srcwin 392680.95083132095 5816991.938620153 393134.43388141005 5817424.944091731 -projwin_srs EPSG:25833 georef_truedop_2023.tiff georef_truedop_2023_split.tiff


but I get this error:
Warning 1: -srcwin 392717 5.81703e+06 393098 5.81739e+06 falls completely outside raster extent. Going on however.

ERROR 3: georef_truedop_2023_split.tiff: Free disk space available is 234466742272 bytes, whereas 9147242338836 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE.
which is weird, because when I translate the outlines to 4326, they are well within the outer outline of the first image. what is wrong here?
Gdalinfo shows the correct bounds for the tiff:
gdalinfo georef_truedop_2023.tiff 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: georef_truedop_2023.tiff
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (13.419277533858136,52.496477481665423)
Pixel Size = (0.000012768825371,-0.000007774143006)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  13.4192775,  52.4964775) ( 13d25' 9.40"E, 52d29'47.32"N)
Lower Left  (  13.4192775,  52.4924971) ( 13d25' 9.40"E, 52d29'32.99"N)
Upper Right (  13.4258152,  52.4964775) ( 13d25'32.93"E, 52d29'47.32"N)
Lower Right (  13.4258152,  52.4924971) ( 13d25'32.93"E, 52d29'32.99"N)
Center      (  13.4225464,  52.4944873) ( 13d25'21.17"E, 52d29'40.15"N)
Band 1 Block=512x4 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=512x4 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=512x4 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=512x4 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha



I suggest reading https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/gdal_translate.html and https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/gdalwarp.html first. Consider if projwin is good to your, or perhaps cutline. Practise with gdal_translate and/or gdalwarp. When you know what you want all the same is possible to do also with programming with Python or some other language.

Hi, thanks for the reply. i updated the question with the progres i have made

A few comments: 1) You have downloaded image from WMS with parameters &crs=EPSG:25833 and bbox=.... It would make much more sense to use those for georeferencing the image than EPSG:4326 bounding box. 2) As documented, srcwin is based on pixel/line location. You do not want to use that. You need to use -projwin and tell with -projwin_srs in which coordinate system the -projwin is. But with the values that you use you seem to select the whole image because they are the same than those that you used in &bbox= for fetching the image from WMS.

I know this is just an example, but in this case why not just request the image as a tiff in epsg:4326 using the BBOX you need.  GetCapabilities response shows epsg:4326 and tiff are supported https://gdi.berlin.de/services/wms/truedop_2023?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Hi @nmtoken i know this explicit wms supports more, but i need a solution for not only this berlin wms.
